# getElementById for several radio inputs

Tags: php, javascript, html

I know you can't give a same id to elements in one page. But i have a list which PHP generates with a SELECT * statemnt, this list shows all the rows in database in a HTML table
each row of data has a radiobox next to it which its value is the id of that row in mysql. what I am trying to do here is when you check the Radio for that row and run the Func, JavaScript gets the Value which is the id number so I can delete that row

Something like this: but again I can't give all the radio the same id

```
var age = document.getElementById('radio').value;
    var queryString = "?id=" + radio;
    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "coderemove.php" + queryString, true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null);
```

When I run this nothing happens, obviously

Comment: just wait, someone will scream JQuery soon

Comment: Why would some IDIOT give me a Vote down for a question!!?? It's a freakin question why would you vote down ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the pure JavaScript approach - imagine the PHP code outputs this:

```
Thing Number 1 <input type="radio" name="myRadioId" value="thingy1" />
Thing Number 2 <input type="radio" name="myRadioId" value="thingy2" />
```

Then our JavaScript code could be:

```
function getRadioValue(radioName){
    // Get all inputs on the page.
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        // Check it is a radio of the correct name and is checked.
        if (inputs[i].type === 'radio' &&
            inputs[i].name === radioName &&
            inputs[i].checked) {

            // We have the checked radio - return its value.
            return inputs[i].value;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

var queryString = "?id=" + getRadioValue('myRadioId');
// Do stuff here
```

But if we use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) - then it becomes much simpler:

```
var queryString = "?id=" + $("input:radio[name=myRadioId]").val();
```

If you don't know JavaScript, and you are looking to program web-pages using it, I encourage you to spend an hour learning the basics of jQuery. It will save you some hassle : )

Comment: Wow, thank you very much. I just started JS, that's why I am not that familiar with it. But I'll start JQuery right away. Thanks Again

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<input name="mygroupname" type="radio" value="1">
<input name="mygroupname" type="radio" value="2">
<input name="mygroupname" type="radio" value="3">
```

and

```
document.getElementsByName('mygroupname');
```

to get the elements in an array.

Comment: Really? For what version? It works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/moopet/WWMF4/ and as far as I can see, that method has worked for the last few Firefoxes at least.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function test() {
    var getRadios = document.getElementById("input")
    for (var x = 0; x < getRadios.length; x++) {
        if ( getRadios[x].type == "radio" && getRadios[x].checked )
            alert(getRadios[x].value)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no such thing as document.getElementsById, since IDs are unique.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to dynamically change the id of radio buttons. The [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) part is:

```
<?php
    $qry = "select * from table_name";
    $res = mysql_query($qry);
?>
<table>
    <?php
        $count = 1;
        while($data=mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><input type = 'radio' value='<?php echo $data
        ['col']?>' id=<?php echo $count;?> onclick="alertId(this.id)"
        name="radio"></td>
        <td><?php echo $data['col'];?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
            $count++;
        }
    ?>
</table>
```

And the JavaScript part is:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function alertId(id) {
        alert(id);
    }
</script>
```

This will alert the id of the clicked radio button and then you can get the value by `documnet.getElementById(id).value`.